# Mongo: how to filter out record that matches two not confitions?

Tags: mongodb

Our document has a 2 fields: type (string) and code (integer)

I must extract all record but exclude all record where both conditions are true

- type: "RTB"
- code: 23

I must see

- MTK 23
- RTB 20

but not see

- RTB 23

I thinked to compose query as is:

```
{ 
  $not:  { 
           $type: "RTB",
           $code: 23 
         } 
}
```

But it's not allowed to use $not as top level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$not` you can use `$ne` operator

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$not": {
      "$and": [
        { "$eq": ["$type", "RTB"] },
        { "$eq": ["$code", 23] }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7gRQKC3CcJm)